# как передавать название класса через миксин

Tags: sass

можно ли в sass передавать название класса через переменную миксина?
 вот так

```
@mixin colors ($qq){
 $qq{ 
  color:red;
 }
}

@include colors(myClass);
```

в итоге хочу получить вот такой результат

```
.myClass{
   color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

разобрался, вдруг кому то пригодится ответ

```
@mixin colors ($qq){
 .#{$qq}{ 
  color:red;
 }
}

@include colors(myClass);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$color: (
  $blue: blue,
  $red: red,
  $yellow: yellow,
);

$border: map-get($color, $blue);
```

Подойдет такой пример, если от этого отталкиваться? :)